# What is meant by "Bulk Equipment Interference"?

Tags: hardware

In a recent [BBC article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-37130455) about the UK's Snoopers Charter it mentions the term `Bulk Equiptment Interference`. It states:

> But he expressed some reservations about a fourth practice - bulk
>   equipment interference, which involves hacking into smart phones or
>   computers over "a large geographical area", saying there was "a
>   distinct (though not yet proven) operational case" for it.

So doing a bit of extra interneting doesn't really uncover much about this term, no wikipedia article or anything. The only extra information it uncovers is [this](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/473753/Factsheet-Bulk_Equipment_Interference.pdf) article by gov.co.uk which is also very vague.

So in practice what is `Bulk Equiptment Interference` apart from just "Hacking things"

Do we know or are the articles purposely vague?

Comment: If you read the article carefully, PDF is given INSIDE the article.  It is just double-talk used by law-maker : Equipment Interference =  man in the middle attack.
https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/546925/56730_Cm9326_WEB.PDF

Comment: So the relevant authority use "interference" instead of "snooping" ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expanded on what @mootmoot said in his comments, Bulk Equipment Interference is an euphemism (i.e Double Speak) for Monitoring internet connected devices over large geographical area.

You could relate this to USA's [PRISM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRISM_(surveillance_program)) project. It essentially means that the UK will monitor your traffic in the interest of national security and it has the legal authority to do so.

While not specified, this most likely revolves around cooperation with telco and mobile providers. These organizations would be the hub that collects data, and passes it on to the GC for data analytics.

Privacy be damned in these modern times.

Answer (score 1):

Because they included the word "Interference", I assumed they meant a disruptive man-in-the-middle attack, like a Harris [StingRay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stingray_phone_tracker); something that actively broadcasts to ensnare victim devices, and may prevent connecting to legitimate infrastructure equipment.

I interpreted this overall to mean they were authorizing the use of non-discriminating broadcast devices to monitor not only the phones of specific terror suspects, but everyone attending a large event, such as a match or a concert.  (And not strictly limited to events, but wherever and whenever they want, really.)

Comment: This is what I interpreted the meaning as well, but didn't know the name of the device. Further reading on a Harris Stingray makes for an interesting read